# Can we totally depend on Database Engine Tuning Advisor?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I read about Database Engine Tuning Advisor and how it can suggest the index for a given query. My question is can I completely depend on these suggestions when creating index ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database tuning advisor *can* be useful for tuning specific queries or a multitude of queries.

***But***

Just be aware that throwing a bunch of indexes on a table can help the performance of one query, while harming the performance of another.  Additionally, the more indexes a table has, the longer writes take due to having to write to multiple indexes.

If you have especially long running queries, you can reference the tuning advisor's suggestions (but try to understand why it's suggesting them before throwing them onto a table willy nilly).

One other (potentially) nice feature is providing a trace file for the advisor to parse.  If you are able to get a "like production" trace, that could potentially give you beneficial indexes to throw on several tables.  By "like production" i mean if you can get a trace that represents production like behavior over a long period of time.  One option is to trace production (See why this can be a bad idea https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/818/using-sql-profiler-on-a-database-thats-in-production)... but be careful this can be pretty heavy handed.  Here's a tutorial on how to do a smaller footprint trace without utilizing the UI:  http://tranpeter.blogspot.com/2013/10/sql-server-proffer-offline.html

Comment: If I provide the DTA with a good trace file, does it will consider other queries when suggest an index for a given query ?

Comment: from what i understand (which could be incorrect) the DTA takes into account all queries provided by the trace file.  Still, this can be overkill on its suggestions, but its suggestions will be based on more "real workflow" within your app, so it *could* be more useful in some regards.  Again though, evaluate the indexes you're actually adding to see if they make sense.

Comment: What is your opinion of the other answer who say absolutely not ?

Comment: I think that Thomas and my answers are pretty similar.  His answer directly answers the question "My question is can I completely depend on these suggestions when creating index ?"  And the answer is, absolutely not. You can take its suggestions as a starting point, but to blindly follow everything the DTA advises would be a bad idea.  You can absolutely use it, but you absolutely cannot use it and it alone. That is how I took the "Absolutely Not" anyhow.

Comment: Thanks, I can't decide who to give the correct answer. Both answer good and deserve to be the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

**Absolutely not**.  The Database Engine Tuning Advisor has a very limited scope, only recommending indexes for a particular workload.  But the actual workload may vary.

For instance, DTA would recommend `index1` for a particular query.  But say that table is the target of heavy data modification, so the benefits of `index1` are so extremely small compared to the overhead and performance impact of maintaining `index1` from the data modifications from a more significant workload. *(that's just an example, but should serve in illustrating how a shotgun approach at indexing can get you into trouble)*

Take DTA's recommendations as just that... **recommendations**.  There is no substitute for the due diligence of testing out the recommended indexing in an actual production-equivalent workload.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and +1

Comment: I want to add, evaluate the execution plan of every query you will use repeatedly with data and get experience in the index creation using the results. You caN explore other tools for tunning.

Comment: Do not you think you are exaggerating when you say absolutely not.